# Como criar uma View com 2 tabelas com colunas diferentes em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Tenho a seguinte query generica:

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "Resumo_vendas" (
    "TIPO_REGISTRO"
    ,"VLR_DESCONTOS"
    ,"VLR_ACRESCIMOS"
    ,"VLR_PIS"
    ,"VLR_COFINS"
    ,"VLR_ICMS"
    ,"DTA_EMISSAO_NOTA"
    ) AS (
    SELECT 1 AS tipo_registro
    ,m01am AS vlr_descontos
    ,m01by AS vlr_acrescimos
    ,m01cia AS vlr_pis
    ,m01cib AS vlr_cofins
    ,m01cic AS vlr_icms
    ,NULL AS dta_emissao_nota FROM tabela1 t01
    )

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT 45 AS tipo_registro
        ,m45am AS vlr_descontos
        ,m45by AS vlr_acrescimos
        ,m45cia AS vlr_pis
        ,m45cib AS vlr_cofins
        ,m45cic AS vlr_icms
        ,M45xa AS dta_emissao_nota FROM tabela45 t45
    );
```

**Meu problema é:
a tabela1 não possui as colunas "VLR_PIS", "VLR_COFINS" e "VLR_ICMS" e na tabela45 sim.
Existe alguma forma de eu criar essa View sem excluir essas colunas?**

Comment: Se tais colunas não existem em sua `tabela1` que valores você quer considerar neste caso? Não é só substituir o nome do campo pelo valor a ser considerado? Por ex. `0 AS VLR_PIS` no lugar de `m01cia AS vlr_pis`.

Comment: Na real, a tabela 45 é continuação da tabela 1, porem esses campos só começaram a ter valor a partir da tabela 45. Por isso na tabela 1 esses campos nem existiam. 
Vou tentar usar esse 0 AS VLR_PIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderia criar essas colunas com o valor artificial NULL.

EX :

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "Resumo_vendas" (
    "TIPO_REGISTRO"
    ,"VLR_DESCONTOS"
    ,"VLR_ACRESCIMOS"
    ,"VLR_PIS"
    ,"VLR_COFINS"
    ,"VLR_ICMS"
    ,"DTA_EMISSAO_NOTA"
    ) AS (
    SELECT 1 AS tipo_registro
    ,m01am AS vlr_descontos
    ,m01by AS vlr_acrescimos
    ,NULL AS vlr_pis
    ,NULL AS vlr_cofins
    ,NULL AS vlr_icms
    ,NULL AS dta_emissao_nota FROM tabela1 t01
    )

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT 45 AS tipo_registro
        ,m45am AS vlr_descontos
        ,m45by AS vlr_acrescimos
        ,m45cia AS vlr_pis
        ,m45cib AS vlr_cofins
        ,m45cic AS vlr_icms
        ,M45xa AS dta_emissao_nota FROM tabela45 t45
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

Olá...

O que importa é que na UNION, todas os retornos sejam iguais em quantidade e tipo, portanto, nas colunas que não existem, coloque null, ou um valor padrão.

Por exemplo:

```sql
select 
    tipo 'pessoa'
    , nome 
    , data_nascimento
    , local_trabalho
from
    pessoas
union all 
select 
    tipo 'animal'
    , nome 
    , data_nacimento
    null local_trabalho
from 
    animais
```

Observe que que nesse caso, animais não tem local de trabalho, mas para manter o número de colunas colocamos o valor **null** para todos os registros.